# Restore bounds or decrease bounds

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-scope, angular-google-maps

In an angularJS/ angular Google maps project I am adding markers on a map. I am able to extend the map's bounds when I add a marker but I want to decrease the bounds when I remove a marker from the map.

As far as I saw there isn't something like decrease-bounds function in the library so I am trying unsuccessfully to create a new bounds object.

```
var restoreBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Any ideas or solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So stupid of me. I needed a coffee break.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.mapInstance = $scope.map.control.getGMap();
    $scope.mapInstance.fitBounds(newMapBoundsRestore);
}, 100);
```